# solving the equation $X^2-nY^2=d$

Tags: diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

we know that equations of the form $X^2-dY^2=Z^2$ have parameter solutions in $\mathbb{Z}$

[see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848313/does-the-special-pell-equation-x2-dy2-z2-have-a-simple-general-parameteriza/1042915#1042915)

but what about equations of the form $X^2-nY^2=d$  where $x,y,z,d \in \mathbb{Z}$ ($X$ and $Y$ are variables)

do they have solutions in general?
what about special case below:

$X^2-17Y^2=14$

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529480/integers-of-the-form-x2-ny2

Comment: do you mean a Pell equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your particular equation has no integral solutions.

First of all, if $7\mid X$ then $7\mid (X^2 - 14) = 17Y^2$ which implies that $7\mid Y$, but then $7^2\mid (X^2 - 17Y^2) = 14$ but that is false. A similar deduction can be made if $7\mid Y$.

Then $X^2$ is congruent to $1$, $2$ or $4$ $\text{(mod) } 7$ and $-17Y^2$ is congruent to $4Y^2$, so also to $1$, $2$ or $4$ $\text{(mod) } 7$.

That means that $X^2 -17Y^2$ can be congruent to one of the following:

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
+ & 1 & 2 & 4 \\ \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 5 \\ 
2 & 3 & 4 & 6 \\ 
4 & 5 & 6 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
$$

So $X^2 -17Y^2 \not\equiv 0 \pmod 7$ but $14 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$.

Answer (score 3):

Dickson gives the complete integer solution in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183485743).

Comment: Doesn't that solve $X^2 -nY^2 = ZW$ with $X,Y,Z,W$ as variables? @OP's question asks about $X^2 -nY^2 = d$ where only $X$ and $Y$ are variables.

Comment: The OP can use Dickson's parameterization and the known $n$ and $d=ZW$ to solve for the variables that comprise $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: So you are saying that the only values of $d$ for which the equation has solutions are the ones where $d = (el^2 + 2flq + gq^2)(en^2 - 2fnr + gr^2)$ for some integral parameters $e,f,g,l,n,q,r$.

Comment: Sort of… In the OP's specific example, we have $n=17$. Using Dickson's parameterization, we can solve (for example) $e=(f^2-17)/g$. Substituting back in, we have $ZW=d=14$, with only four integral possibilities (factorizations) to consider — we can quickly determine [as you did, using other means] that there are no solutions.